# How to change VizFrame color for "dual_stacked_combination"

Tags: sapui5

I'm implementing the VizFrame component for an SAP ui5 project, so i used the "dual_stacked_combination" type.

When I try to apply the color property, it doesn't work, and the result is some stacked columns with the gradient of the same color.

```
var scales = [{
'feed': 'color','palette': ['#ff9900', '#0090ea', '#00ff00', '#ff0000', '#f200ff', '#ffe100', '#00ffed', '#039660','#9e9e9e','#000000']}];

oVizFrameLine2.setVizScales(scales);
```

I want every part of the stacked column to have its own color

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use **vizProperties** and set **plotArea.colorPalette** to get different colors for each stacked segment

```
<viz:VizFrame id="idVizFrame" height="50%" width="100%"
 vizType='stacked_column' vizProperties="{ plotArea : {colorPalette: 
 ['#f00','#0f0','#00f']} }" >
```